# JavaScript convert number into currency and copy negative currency into another textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to convert number into currency and copy that currency value as a negative number into another textbox.

Here, when the onblur event is fired first time, it is displaying the result as expected but everytime I put focus into textbox - it is adding $ Sign.

**Desired Output:-**

[image]

`<td>
 <asp:TextBox CssClass="from" runat="server" Text="$0.00" BackColor="Yellow" onkeyup="javascript:copy(event)" onblur="javascript:currency(event)" />                 </td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" CssClass="to" runat="server" Text="$0.00" ClientIDMode="Static" BackColor="Yellow"></asp:TextBox>
</td>`

JavaScript Function:

```
function copy(event) {

        var parentRow = $(event.target).parents('tr');

        var fromVal = parentRow.children('td').find('.from').val();

        parentRow.children('td').find('.to').val(fromVal);

    }



    function currency(event) {

        var parentRow = $(event.target).parents('tr');

        var val1 = parentRow.children('td').find('.from').val();

        var number = '$' + val1.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");

        parentRow.children('td').find('.from').val(number);

        var buyerNumber = '($' + val1.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + ')';

        parentRow.children('td').find('.to').val(buyerNumber);

    }
```

The reason for using Parent Element is I need same functionality for multiple Textboxes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I need to check position of $ Sign -

```
var val1 = parentRow.children('td').find('.textbox-seller').val();

        if(val1.indexOf("$") != 0){
            var number = '$' + val1.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
        }
        else {
            number = val1.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
        }
```

By checking the position of "$" sign - I can achieve desired result.